# hide one application in application menu of android

Tags: android

I am new to this Android application Programing.

I need to know the thing that, disable and hiding of one application from application menu list.

instead of deleting the entire application, that need to do some other changes to hide and disabling any application from menu list.

Answer (score 3):

If it is your application that you wish to hide, you can enable or disable the activity that has the `LAUNCHER` `Intent` filter via the `PackageManager`.

If it is somebody else's application that you wish to hide, that is not possible except via firmware.

Comment: will you please elaborate this answer

Answer (score 1):

Your manifest declares which components of your application are and aren't shown in the application draw. You can not modify this from within your application so you will be unable to hide your app programatically.