# How to hide app icon in app drawer programmatically

Tags: android

We know how to hide an app in app drawer (launcher) referring to [hide one application in application menu of android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218127/hide-one-application-in-application-menu-of-android) , however, could we hide app itself within its code? I mean is it possible to remove activity's intent filter

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

dynamically within its code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The manifest is read by the Android package manager system when it is installed.  Afterwards, these values are read from it's own datastore and not from the manifest so without modifying the PackageManager or installing a different version of the app, these settings cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this isn't possible. The manifest states what your application can or can't do. 
Think about permissions : they are required for proper code execution, but you can't change them once your application is installed. That should be the same for intent filters.

Comment: I installed ice cream sandwich theme for ADW launcher from the market . After the installation, I get an app icon in the drawer and this app has such a feature to remove the icon. it works, so I think there must be some methods to do this.perhaps needs hidden APIs and reflection.

Comment: I know what you mean -- HideIt Pro -- this app can hide other applications from the drawer. But 1st, it needs root permission. 2nd, it can only hide other applications (from outside not from inside code). But you still gave a hint and actually I thought about it before.